# Angular 2 RC4 + Router Path Variables with special characters

Tags: angularjs, angular

Can Any one Suggest me how we can call parameters (contains special characters) from the url's. below is my present code to call param.

`ngOnInit() {
         this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          let accountrefID = params['accountReferenceID'];
          console.log("paramerter is "+accountrefID);
         this._accountservice.getAccountSummary(accountrefID).subscribe(accountSummary => {
            this.accountSummary = accountSummary;
          });
        })
      }`

my URL is looks like

```
http://localhost:4200/account/fhdjfhdjfj343445  -- its working
https://localhost:4200/account/fjdhfj$W$Wfjkdjfk=  -- its working but the
```

param is taking before special characters 
my router class is like below:

`import {RouterConfig, provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
    import {AccountSummaryComponent} from "./+accountSummary/account-summary.component";
    export const routes: RouterConfig = [
      {
        path: 'accountSummary/:accountReferenceID', component: AccountSummaryComponent
      }
    ];
    export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
      provideRouter(routes)
    ];`

Please help me out where i can change the code to get right params including special characters.  Presently i am using RC4.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Comment: i have tried different approach, while sending the url i am using encoding method from different application.

Answer (score 0):

To pass special characters in parameter you have to URL encode it.

you may see reference how to do that at [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

you may try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: the above article was helped me partially. for work around i am using encoding url from different application. any ways thanks alot